# css media queries always defaults to the last query in the css document

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to implement some basic [css media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) into my web app. No matter how I order the queries in the CSS document it will always use the last query.

My CSS is layout out

```
basic styles{
   ...
}
@mediaqueries{
   styles{
      ...
   }
}
```

I dont know if its an ordering issue but no matter how large I make the brower or testing device it will always the last query in the document.

Media Queries:

```
Regular CSS{
   ...
}
@media screen  and (orientation : landscape) {
   //changes background image for devices
}
@media screen and (orientation : portrait) {
   //changes background image for devices
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 240px) and (max-device-width: 320px) {
   ...
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   ...
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 640px) {
   ...
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 640px) and (max-device-width: 800px) {
   ...
}
```

> And So on

Meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

> Things I have tried

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 640px) and (max-device-width: 800px)
```

instead of

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 640px) and (max-device-width: 800px)
```

And

```
@media all and (min-device-width: 640px) and (max-device-width: 800px)
```

instead of

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 640px) and (max-device-width: 800px)
```

Any ideas? My css is 1026 lines so not practical to paste the whole document sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ordering the media queries, you should make sure the `max-width` properties go down from the highest value, so it should be just the opposite from your provided code.

The way I usually tend to deal with Media Queries is following:

```
@media (min-height: 992px)
{
   *css here*
}
@media (max-width: 991px)
{
   *css here*
}
@media (max-width: 768px)
{
   *css here*
}
@media (max-width: 499px)
{
   *css here*
}
```

And don't get me wrong, you can combine both min and max values and it is totally correct.

Comment: I changed the order to match your answer, its still using the largest size for the query

Comment: I got it working with your method, i just had to add the min and max values to each query. The same way I had just ordered the way you suggested. Thanks.